# Store procedure returns unexpected value but works fine

Tags: asp.net, sql, c#-4.0, ado.net, c#-3.0

my project is working fine but weirdly. I wrote store procedure which inserts record if record already doesn't exist then it inserts and return 1 else returns 0
In asp.net .cs code i put a condition if result returned it 1 then return true else return false and it does that, perfectly but it actually SP isn't returning 1, it returns 0 in both condition but program works fine for both 1 and 0 condition, why ? i don't understand.

SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddCoordinates]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

    @AddedDateTime varchar(50),
    @IMEI varchar(50),
    @RecordedDateTime varchar(50),
    @Latitude varchar(50),
    @Longitude varchar(50),
    @IsParking bit,
    @result int output
AS
BEGIN

    --set @result = (select count(*) from dbo.Coordinates where IMEI =@IMEI)

    If Not exists(select IMEI from dbo.Coordinates where IMEI =@IMEI)
    Begin
     insert into dbo.Coordinates 
     values (@AddedDateTime, @IMEI, @RecordedDateTime, @Latitude, @Longitude, @IsParking) 
     Select @result=1
    End
    Else If exists(select IMEI from dbo.Coordinates where IMEI =@IMEI)
    Begin
     Select @result=0
    End

END
```

.BLL

```
public class BLL
{
    String conStr;
    String query;
    SqlConnection sqlCon;
    SqlCommand sqlCom;

    public BLL()
    {

        conStr = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        query  = "";
        sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        sqlCom = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);

    }

    public bool InsertCoordinates(string[] parts) 
    {

        sqlCom.CommandText = "AddCoordinates";
        sqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        int result;

        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@AddedDateTime", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = parts[0].ToString();
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@IMEI", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = parts[1].ToString();
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@RecordedDateTime", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = parts[2].ToString();
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@Latitude", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = parts[3].ToString(); ;
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@Longitude", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = parts[4].ToString(); ;
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@IsParking ", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = ((parts[5].ToString().Trim()).Equals("0")) ? true : false;
        SqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter("@result", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add(sqlParam);
        sqlCom.Parameters["@result"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        try
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            result = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery());


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;

        }
        finally 
        {
            sqlCon.Close();
        }

        if(result == 1)
           return true;
        else
           return false;
    }
}
```

.Webservice

```
public class GPSWebservice : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public GPSWebservice () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public bool insertCoordinates(string[] parts) 
    {
        BLL bll = new BLL();
        return bll.InsertCoordinates(parts);
    }

}
```

.default.cs

```
protected void btnInsertCoordinates_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GPSWebservice gpsws = new GPSWebservice();
        string[] parts = "2013-03-31,ALFALAH-8000,2013-03-31,1099,9888, 0".Split(',');
        Response.Write( gpsws.insertCoordinates(parts));
    }
```

i am putting break point at result= convert.toint32(sqlCom.executenonquery()), i tried ExecuteScalar() but same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here

```
result = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery());
```

must be

```
sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
result = sqlCom.Parameters["@result"].Value;
```

or, in your case

```
result = sqlParam.Value;
```

The output parameter isn't return value.

You can change the above code as

```
SqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter("@result", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
sqlCom.Parameters.Add(sqlParam);
```

to be more readable.

Comment: but why does my code is working for 0,1 conditions even though values being returned are not 0,1.. just 0,

Comment: What you mean? Your SP initializes the `@result` as is.

Comment: i mean the when record exists then .cs code should return false which is based on 0 or true if record doesn't exists, and this depends on values being returned from SP but if SP is returning 0 all the time that how does if else in .cs is working ?

Comment: Why you think that SP always returns 0?

Comment: when i debug it then result is storing 0 in either case

Comment: see, when record not exist then SP should return 1 and my .cs code should return TRUE, yes my code does and should return false if SP returns 0 (when record exists) and yes it does but when i check value in result while in debugging then it always store 0 so how it is working for true and false

Comment: When you execute SP from management studio does it return correct values.

Comment: So, do you achieve your goal? Where was the problem?